# Email format type JAVA

Tags: java, methods, return, return-type

I have a task to write a return type method which takes String as an argument and returns boolean. If the String matches with the requirements it returns true else false.

- So it should not have any space, and more then 1 '@'and format must be 2>chars@2>chars.2>chars so it should be xyz@xyz.com is true but if any part of it less then 3 it should return to false. I checked so many forums but all i can find regex and we didn't learn anything about it. I could able to do this much but i just couldn't figure out how can i specifically set length of each part and set it as true or false. I'm missing so many and this is all i able to complete;

```
     public static boolean emailAddress(String str) {
            if (str.contains(" "))
                return false;
            boolean flag = true;
            if(str3.length()> 11)
            for (int i = 0; i < str3.length(); i++) {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < str3.length(); j++) {
                    if (str3.charAt(i) == str3.charAt(j)) {
                        flag = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(flag)
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Split the problem into multiple parts. Meaning, first take substrings from your original `String`. For that, it might be a good idea to use [`substring()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) in combination with [`indexOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-). Read the javadoc for more information. Then for each substring, check if the constraints are met. Of course you will also need to check if `@` and `.` are available and in the correct order.

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint! I will work on that now, appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would approach it:

```java
public static boolean isEmailAddress(String str)
{
    if(str.trim().equals("")) // Checking if it is an empty string
    {
        return false;
    }

    boolean flag = true;

    int atIndex = str.indexOf("@"); // Get the index of @
    if (atIndex == -1)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Slice your email str and get only the characters before the @
    // Check whether the length and the characters are as you want them.
    
    // Do the same thing about the string between @ and .
    
    // and then do the same thing about the sliced string after .

}
```

Check [`substring()`](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-substring) and [`indexOf()`](https://www.w3schools.com/java/ref_string_indexof.asp).

For anyone who needs it.

This should be one of the Regex to match your requirement:

```regex
[a-zA-Z_0-9]{2,}@[a-zA-Z_0-9]{2,}\.[a-zA-Z_0-9]{2,}
```

- [a-zA-Z_0-9] it requires one of the characters, from a-z,A-Z or 0-9
- {2,} it requires two or more from one of the characters inside.

Comment: "_I checked so many forums but all i can find regex and we didn't learn anything about it."_ - they are not asking about a regex to solve the problem.

Comment: @maloomeister thank you, did not read it properly. Will change my answer asap.

Comment: It would probably also be in their interest not to give them a fully fleshed-out answer, since they are still learning and this seems to be homework. Provide them with hints on what to improve / what to do differently instead. There is no learning benefit if you provide them with a full answer.

Comment: @maloomeister good point. I edit my answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A few hints instead of complete solution:

Check if the input string...

1. has `@` and `.` (there could be two or three period's as some domain uses `.co.in`)
2. does not have any white spaces (`' '`)
3. does not start with special characters (`'#'`, `'^'`)

If possible, do not check for length of each part, as sometimes `.in` also valid domain.